# Setting up Nginx with proxy_pass and IPV6

Tags: nginx, proxypass

The following code results in a `502 Bad Gateway`. When I replace it with an IPV4 address the code works. How do I use proxy_pass with an IPV6 address?

```
server {
        listen 80 ipv6only=on;
        listen [::]:80 ipv6only=on;
        server_name webcam.foo.bar;

        location / {
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
                proxy_pass http://[2a03:2880:f003:c07:face:b00c::2]:8080;
        }
```

Comment: Are you sure your host you are proxying toward supports ipv6?

Comment: The example address above is bogus - I can connect directly to my web cam running at an address that is formatted like this: http://[2a03:2880:f003:c07:face:b00c::2]:8080 in the browser.

Comment: @JZ did you find you the issue? the listen seems weird to me. You specify "listen 80" which is supposed to be ipv4 and then set "ipv6only=on" ? Did you make sure the target is reachable with curl?